# How to associate a private key (.key) file to a ssl certificate (from GoDaddy) to install on IIS

Tags: openssl, iis, windows-server, ssl-certificate

I have ssl certificate file downloaded from GoDaddy which contains .pem file .crt file and .p7b file. I have a private key generated in .key extension. I need to assign the same to the certificate i received from Godaddy and install the same in IIS certificates.

I have created .cer file from .crt sslcertificate.cer

The issue actually is, when I install the certificate in IIS using the option "complete certificate request" and add the details it is showing in the certificate list. But when refresh or go to other options and return to the certificates list I cannot see the new certificate I just added, it vanished.

By googling I can understand the issue is due to the private key not associated with the certificate. When I checked the certificate itself, I can see there is no key Icon showing. I have tried adding via openssl command to make it as a p12K file with key also attached but 'Its result is password is required' and exits the command line as per the search findings it should ask for the password (I doubt there is a password already set in that key file or something). I have also tried certutil -repairstore my "serial number" command but it asks for smart device connect.

[image: this is what am getting when trying to create a .pfx file]

First I have tried creating a new key since this private key was an old one and am not sure in the creation time whether someone put password in it that is why pasword is asking. So I created a new key file 'newkey.key' and try to make .pfx file with that but it shows this key is not the correct one associated with .cer/crt file. Then I have tried creating a .key file from the the pem file i have received but it still says cannot retrieve data from pem file

Comment: "I need to assign the same to the certificate" - They should already be connected.  The public and private key when generated are linked to one another. "I can see there is no key Icon showing." - This is a nothing burger, icons are linked by the file extension, by default an application is not linked to those file extensions. TLS keys are only good, if you did not generate the public and private key at the sametime, you can use neither for your use.

Comment: It is much better to copy/paste text into your question than screenshots.  As you can see, the writing on that screenshot is barely readable (or is that my age?).  Pasted text can be copied and it can be indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've overwritten your original `.key` file, then you are out of luck.  Unless you have a backup, the certificate is now useless.

Assuming you have the original...

You first need to join your *original* `.key` file with the `.pem` received from GoDaddy to create a PKCS#12 file:

```
openssl.exe pkcs12 -export -in sslcert.pem -inkey sslcert.key -out sslcert.pfx -passout pass:password
```

(Note: if you're using OpenSSL version 3 and/or older versions of Windows, you may need to append `-nomac -certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES` to the above command)

Next, double-click on the created `.pfx` file to import it.  In the import wizard, choose **Local Machine** and click on **Next**. On the next page, click **Next** again.  On the Private key protection page, enter `password` in the **Password** box and click on **Next**.  On the Certificate Store page, select **Place all certificates in the following store**, click **Browse** and choose **Personal** before clicking **OK** to close the selection dialogue, then clicking **Next**.  Click **Finish**.

You now need to import the intermediate CA certificate into the store.  Double-click on the received `.p7b` file to open it.  In the certmgr window that appears, double-click on **Certificates**.  A list of certificates stored in the p7b will appear.  Double-click on the intermediate CA to open it.  The intermediate CA is the one where the **Issued To** and **Issued By** differ.  On the one I've just downloaded from GoDaddy, the certificate is issued to *Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2*, but yours might be different.  Once the certificate is displayed, click on **Install Certificate...**.  A dialogue, similar to the one used to import the pfx above opens.  On the welcome page, select **Local Machine** and click **Next**. On the Certificate Store page, select **Place all certificates in the following store**, click **Browse** and choose **Intermediate Certification Authorities** before clicking **OK** to close the selection dialogue, then clicking **Next**.  Click **Finish**.

Now, move to **IIS Manager** and navigate to the site to which this certificate will be bound.  Click on **Bindings...** in the **Actions** tab (right-hand pane), select the **https** binding and click **Edit...**.  In Edit Site Binding dialogue, your imported certificate should be visible under **SSL certificate**.  Select it, then click **OK**, then **Close**.

Once you've verified everything is working, you need to delete the `.key` file as it has the private key in clear-text, and the `.pfx` file as it is protected by the password "password".  Alternatively, create the `.pfx` with a better password and store it somewhere safe in-case you need it to restore your IIS server at some point.

For future reference, it would be easier to generate the certification request using Windows native tools.  That way, the private key is already in the Windows store and all you need to do is import the returned certificate, maybe the intermediate CA (if GoDaddy have changed it) and bind the certificate to IIS.

Comment: Thanks @garethTheRed for the help and your time for giving this detailed Information. The issue is resolved now, i have hardcored the password and created pk12 file as you mentioned in the firsr command line. 

Then i have imported the pk12 file in IIS with the entered password.

https://support.globalsign.com/ssl/ssl-certificates-installation/install-pfxpkcs12-internet-information-services-iis-7#:~:text=Click%20Import%20on%20the%20right,the%20bindings%20for%20your%20website.